# Response from edge.create if Like clicker has no FB page

Tags: facebook, facebook-like, subscribe

I'm subscribing to a Like button on my page to notify me when someone clicks the Like button.  I then give this user a discount for telling their friends about the site.  But what if the user doesn't have a Facebook page?  Will I still get a call at my handler function.  The Response passed by the edge.create call to the handler is just the URL that was liked, so there doesn't seem to be any flag passed that tells me that the user didn't really post anything to a FB page.  How can I handle this and not be giving discounts for nothing?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What do you mean by "user has no FB page"?  Not every Facebook user will also have a Facebook page.  I only have pages on my Facebook user account are there solely for testing purposes.  If I wasn't developing apps with the Facebook API, then I wouldn't have any at all.  So requiring your users to have a Facebook page may not be in your best interest. Just let them like your website using their normal Facebook user account.

Comment: My understanding is that if you put a Like button somewhere on your web site and a visitor clicks it, Facebook brings up a window where that person can enter a comment and then the comment, some things from your page and your URL get placed on the person's Facebook page, where their FB friends can see it. My question is, what if someone clicked that Like button but Facebook couldn't find any FB page to post the comment to because this person had absolutely no involvement with FB. Is there any way I would know that from the notification I get back from the edge.create call?

Comment: Ok, thanks for clarifying.  The thing is, how can a person leave a comment or even like something unless they're logged into facebook?  When I'm logged out of facebook and try to click like, Facebook forces me to sign in. Same with the comments plugin.

Comment: Exactly!  But I'm giving the person a discount for clicking the Like button.  If they can't fulfill  their part of the deal by telling their FB friends about me I don't want to give the discount. FB gives me feedback now,  through the edge.create call, that the Like button was clicked.  Do they also provide any feedback if they were not able to post a comment to a FB page for this Like button click because the user has no FB page?

Comment: "Do they also provide any feedback if they were not able to post a comment to a FB page for this Like button click because the user has no FB page? " There is no event for canceling an attempt to click the like button when not logged in.